# How to increase flow to upper water outlets

Tags: pipe

If I open one of the large faucets on the lower floor, I get almost no flow in the upper showers.

All the pipes 3/4" from the meter to every outlet. If I increase the size of the section of pipe that distributes the water to the other pipes will that result in an increased flow?

This section is about 5 meters long and has 4 derivations.

Comment: If you increase the pressure of your system that could help but the flow will always take the path of least resistance. Adding flow restrictors on the large faucets could also reduce the problem.

Comment: I'm using water straight from the company supply, the pressure is about 2 bar in the upper floor, and 2.5 bar in the faucet. I could only get more pressure if I added a eletric pressurizer, but I'm not sure if that would be effective.
Do you think that increasing the pipe size will have little effect on the flow?

Comment: Increasing the area won't help at all. The problem appears when you open a faucet on a lower level, meaning the pressure drop from the flow to that faucet is large enough that the upper flows have very little pressure remaining. Having a booster pump for the upper floors *only* would help.

Comment: What this sounds like is a restriction on the meter side of your house. Simplest possible thing could be that the shutoff valve at the meter is only half open. Or if you have a shutoff valve on your own property it is restricting flow. How old is the house? My house's shut-off valves are brass gate valves and corroded and mineralized, and could get jammed in any position--closed, half- open, full open.  Built 1970. I once tried to use one, never again will I use them. I use the cutoff on the city side of the meter.

Comment: I'm just finishing building it, all shutoffs are open.

Comment: In my one-story house the main water line is I think 3/4", but definitely the spurs to each fixture are 1/2".  Inside the house there are three unrestricted faucets--the clothes washer, the tub spigot, and a utility sink in the garage; all are fed by a 1/2" line.  There are two toilets and two outside unrestricted faucets both fed by 1/2".  I have not determined the effect of turning on the utility sink full on while someone is showering.

Comment: The pipes 3/4, but the outlets (Spurs!?) are 1/2, all outlets are unrestricted (I think!?). The problematic outlet definitely has less resistance as it has fewer bends and curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### That's normal in every house everywhere.

If someone's in the shower, don't open the faucet!  That's a basic rule of cohabiting a house with anyone.

If you really want to engineer your way around that, you'll need flow restrictors on every faucet, and a temperature compensating blending valve on the shower.   How much flow does that faucet need?  You may be thinking "the absolute maximum possible", well, then, OK, you can't use it at the same time as other faucets, because it's taking it all, *as you intend.*

Since you've made all the pipes huge, the limiting factor is now the water supply coming in from the city.

The difference in bar pressure is explained by the difference in height between floors. 0.5 bar is the weight of a column of water 16'9" tall or about 5 metres.

Comment: I only lived in a two floor house once, and this wasn't a problem (or we never noticed), now I'm finishing the building of my own house and testing craziness ensues... The pipes aren't huge, they are standard PVC  and CPVC pipes used in Brazil.

Comment: If you had constricted piping in your old place, or flow restrictors, perhaps it wasn't noticeable. There is no possible way to make pressure equal on different floors due to the basic laws of physics.  You have to allow 0.1 bar per metre, that is what water weighs. Can't be avoided.  A 3/4" pipe is 2.25x as large in cross-section as 1/2 such as we commonly use here. You have built it well, and this is a side-effect.